# SSRS Guest User Permissions

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2019 hosted on a local server to deliver reporting functionality.  I am struggling to grant user access using a guest account.

I have created a guest account on the server pc and added the user \Guest as a system user in both the home folder and site settings of the SSRS directory.  The guest user can log in to the directory and see reports, but when the user tries to access the report they are prompted for login details again.  The database login details are a generic username and password.

[image]

This is where the user gets stuck; they keep getting prompted for their username and password.  When they enter them correctly, the security prompt just opens again.  The report is set to inherit permissions from the parent folder, and the user appears on the report security tab with browser permissions.

[image]

I have tried adding the SSRS directory as a trusted site on the server, but am still running into this issue.  Is it something simple that I have overlooked?

Comment: How's your report's data source set up? It sounds like it doesn't have credentials and it's prompting the user for their database credentials (which they don't have).

Comment: The report's data source is set up to login using a generic username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the server pc to the domain network solved my issue.

https://adamtheautomator.com/add-computer-to-domain/